# Object from external script undefined in ie and firefox

Tags: javascript

I'm working on building a javascript widget that users will be able to include on their websites which will display data from our web application. The main file which a user will include `w1.js` contains the following:

```
var MYLIBRARY = MYLIBRARY || (function(){

    var _args = {};
    var jQuery;

    function main(){

        //simply display loaded jquery version as a test
        jQuery('#mylibrary-w1-content').text(jQuery.fn.jquery);

    }

    function scriptLoadHandler(){

        jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
        main();

    }

    return {

      init: function(Args){

          _args = Args;

          if(window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '3.3.1'){

              var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
              script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
              script_tag.setAttribute("src", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js");

              if(script_tag.readyState){

                  script_tag.onreadystatechange = function(){ // for old versions of ie

                      if(this.readyState === 'complete' || this.readyState === 'loaded'){
                          scriptLoadHandler();
                      }

                  };

              } else {
                  script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
              }

              (document.getElementsByName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);

          } else {

              jQuery = window.jQuery;
              main();

          }

      }  

    };



/* END OF LIBRARY
*******************************************************************************/    
}());
```

The code which users include on their website is as follows:

```
<script src="//thewebsite.com/widgets/w1.js"></script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){MYLIBRARY.init(["somevalue"]);}, false);
</script>
<div id="mylibrary-w1-content"></div>
```

Everything is functioning as expected in chrome, however ie and firefox (thought this was just an ie issue until it didn't work in firefox, thought that was odd) return an error message in the console `ReferenceError: MYLIBRARY is not defined`.

My initial thought was that `w1.js` had not completed loading before the call to `MYLIBRARY`, however the `addEventListener('load')` appears to be functioning as expected, unless I've missed something or am doing something incorrectly.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Normally calling an IIFE is like `(function () { ... })();` which isn’t what you have.  Checking deeper it seems that either order of the final parens is ok, so maybe it doesn’t matter.

Comment: @James I went ahead and changed that line as I believe you are correct. Unfortunately that wasn't the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of additional troubleshooting I discovered what was causing this issue. It was not related to javascript. The url where `w1.js` was being loaded from is an internal test site which uses a self signed ssl cert. The reason this was not working in firefox or ie, is because exceptions for this certificate did not exist in firefox or ie, therefore when the call was made, the file was never returned. Adding the exceptions solved the issue.